# plotting wind stress in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a data file, which includes wind speed and wind direction (as shown below).

data:

```
Date & Time    Wind speed   wind direction
1/1/2013 0:00   3.81           196.97
1/1/2013 6:00   4.18           216.86
1/1/2013 12:00  2.84           10.95
1/1/2013 18:00  2.67           26.15
1/2/2013 0:00   2.68           359.15
1/2/2013 6:00   2.54           34.52
1/2/2013 12:00  3.65           41.86
1/2/2013 18:00  1.94           84.80
1/3/2013 0:00   1.51           83.81
1/3/2013 6:00   1.87          162.18
1/3/2013 12:00  2.99          104.94
1/3/2013 18:00  2.74          170.23
```

I want to plot this time series with arrow and magnitude like below picture,
would you mind helping me?

[image]

Comment: Have you already read the doc about the function `feather`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I give you an example using quiver, quiver accept a x and y vector so you can put your date as the x vector.

```
close all
len = 50; %size of the smaple
date = exp(linspace(1,5,len)) %random date
speed = linspace(0,2,len)'; %speed vector
direction = linspace(0,360,len)'; %direction vector
direction = ((direction/360)*4*pi)-2*pi %[0-360] to [-2*pi,2*pi]
[u,v] = pol2cart(direction,speed); %polar to cartesian coordinate

%we plot the result
quiver(date, zeros(size(u)), u, v); %quiver(x,y,u,v), where y = zeros(size(u))
hold on
%we add a central line
plot(date,zeros(size(u)))
```

To transform your date into a vector you should use the function `datenum`

**RESULT:**

[image]